# Combinatorics - placing stones on the chessboard

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can we place 6 red, 6 green and 6 blue stones on a 5 × 5 chessboard so that some row or column is entirely covered by stones of the same color?

Comment: Entirely, or only?

Comment: Actually, I'm having trouble seeing how this works.  Can you give an example of a satisfactory arrangement?

Comment: Sorry, edited ..

Comment: There are $18$ stones and $25$ squares, so this definitely needs clarification. Moreover, it would be good to show context or otherwise explain what you've tried or what your difficulties are.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: The question is perfectly clear; no clarification is required.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: It wasn't before the edit.

Comment: @Brian: The edit preceded the comment in question, however.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: It did, but I presumed it took a while to type in the comment.  We're probably deep enough in the rathole now. :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: I suggest using an inclusion-exclusion argument. Suppose that the first row is covered with red stones. There are $20$ ways to place the remaining red stone, $\binom{19}6$ ways to place the green stones, and $\binom{13}6$ ways to place the red stones, so there are $20\binom{19}6\binom{13}6$ arrangements that have the first row completely covered with red stones. The same is true for each of the $10$ row and columns, so there are $200\binom{19}6\binom{13}6$ arrangements that have a row or column completely covered with red stones.

Clearly there are the same number of arrangements that have a row or column completely covered with green stones, and the same number again that have a row or column completely covered with blue stones.

Now calculate similarly how many arrangements have a row or column completely covered with green stones **and** a row or column completely covered with green stones. Do the same for red and blue and for green and blue.

Finally, calculate similarly how many arrangements have a row or column completely covered with green stones, a row or column completely covered with red stones, and a row or column completely covered with blue stones. Then apply the usual inclusion-exclusion calculation to get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot actually.

Comment: @Luried: You’re welcome; glad it helped.

Comment: I got [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3*10*20*(19+choose+6)*(13+choose+6)-3*2*(5+choose+2)*15*14*(13+choose+6)%2B2*(5+choose+3)*15*14*13) result. What do you think about it?

Comment: @Luried: It’s okay except for the last term: once you fill $3$ rows or $3$ columns, there are only $10$ squares left, not $15$, so it should be $2\binom53\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8$. (That looks like a slip of the mind, not an actual failure of understanding.)